# Python pandas: how to write to csv in certain cells without header

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following variables.

```
num1 = '1'
num2 = '2'
num3 = '3'
num4 = '4'
num5 = '5'
num6 = '6'
num7 = '7'
num8 = '8'
```

Using jupyter notebook, I want to write to csv with 4 values on the 1st row to the left and 4 values on the 2nd row to the left without header and index.

I am expecting to see this in csv. How should I do it?
[image]

In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), there is this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})
df.to_csv(index=False)
```

I am not sure how to modify this part

```
{'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']}
```

to fit mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 df.to_csv('test.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

i fix it after you edited the post.

```
list1 = [num1,num2,num3,num4]
list2 = [num5,num6,num7,num8]
list1, list2
df = pd.DataFrame(list1).T
df = df.append(pd.Series(list2),ignore_index=True)
df
```

Comment: How should I modify the middle part `{'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']}`?

Comment: @hongkongbboy I am not sure that i can understand the problem. do you need to create a df also ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to put 4 items in the 1st row and 4 items in the second row when I write to a csv file. The documentation only shows how to do it with headers. The excel file picture is the result that I want.

Comment: I think something like this `df = pd.DataFrame({'0':[num1, num5], '1':[num2, num6], '2':[num3, num7], '3':[num4, num8]})
df.to_csv('testing.csv', index=False, header=False)`. Do you know if I am writing it correctly?

Comment: @hongkongbboy ok please check the answer again. I tried to write as step by step so this is not best practice; but easy to understand.